# Должны ли Entity-классы реализовывать Serializable

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, java-8

Смотря старые видео и статьи по Hibernate обнаружил, что все Entity в их примерах реализуют интерфейс Serializable. Один парень на видео даже сказал, что без этого хибернейт ляжет с ошибкой, потому что по сути передача в БД подразумевает сериализацию. Суть вопроса в том, что сейчас уже из всех примеров, которые я видел, никто не реализует в Entity-классах этот интерфейс, и я не исключение. При этом хибернейт спокойно себе работает и ни на что не жалуется. Так вот, нужно ли Entity-классам реализовывать данный интерфейс или это уже пережиток прошлого?

Comment: ну если никто этого не делает и оно работает, то ответ вроде сам собой напрашивается, разве нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate не занимается сериализацией Entity, поэтому для локального использования реализовывать Serializable в Entity необязательно. Однако Entity может быть ещё и Java бином и передаваться куда-то дальше по сети или как-то иначе. Именно поэтому спецификация JavaBeans (в параграфе 5.5) требует, чтобы Java бины реализовывали Serializable или Externalizable интерфейс. Соответствие реализации Entity требованиям JavaBeans считается "best practice".

https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/